# How does this line of code in this loop work?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

Can someone please explain to me what the last line of this loop does? It's a snippet from a word jumble program that is an example from a book I am learning from. Thank you.

```
import random
WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
correct = word
jumble = " "

while word:
  position = random.randrange(len(word))
  jumble += word[position]

  word = word[:position] + word[(position +1):]
```

Comment: [Slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Insert ``print word`` inside the loop to see what is going on.

Comment: Please be more specific. I understand the [:position], its the next part and how the 2 interact that is confusing me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cuts out the character at index `position`:

```
>>> word = "python"
>>> position = 3
>>> 
>>> word[:position] + word[(position +1):]
'python'
```

Our string here was `"python"`:

```
p  y  t  h  o  n
0  1  2  3  4  5
         ^
```

It therefore makes sense that for `position = 3` the result is `"python"`, with the `'h'` missing.

In the future always try to test these things with a simplified example, usually they'll give you insight in to exactly what's going on.

See also: [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry for bothering you guys needlessly. I didn't think to do this. :-/